# Parsing first middle and last name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that parses first, middle and last name from complete name.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = 'martin'

SELECT first_name = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 3)
            END
        )
    ,mi = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            END
        )
    ,last_name = (PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 1))
```

So the problem is, this query works fine when both first and last name are entered. Like @name = 'Martin Joe' works fine. But when the input is a single name @name = 'Martin',it is making that as last name and throwing first and MI as null.

### Current output:

```
@name = 'Martin'
First name - Null
MI - Null
Last name - Martin
```

### Desired output:

```
@name = 'Martin'
First name - Martin
MI - Null
Last name - Null
```

it is supposed to show firstname as 'Martin, MI and Lastname as null. Any help?!

Comment: What if you encounter `@name = 'Smith'`?

Comment: Same output. I get Smith as lastname instead of first name

Comment: @Rick Peter B's point is that in *that* case, the fact that you get it as the last name is probably correct. Think more about your requirements.

Comment: Clever use of `PARSENAME`. +1.

Comment: For that matter -- is 'Martin' a first name, or a last name?

Comment: What's the logic behind determining that `Smith` is a last name, but `Martin` is a first name?

Comment: Martin is the firstname

Comment: To clarify, how is your query supposed to know that `Martin` is a first name, not a last name and, conversely, that `Smith` is a last name, not a first name? Martin is both a common first name and last name (Ricky Martin, for instance)

Comment: You have no idea what kind of can of worms you've opened.

Comment: Obligatory link. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: There are already a [bunch of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+first+name) about names in SQL. However, your bigger issue seems to be a naive understanding of names. What about names that don't conform to the `First Middle Last` pattern? In a lot of Asian countries, the surname comes first. In a lot of Spanish-speaking countries, someone can have multiple last names (which may or may not have hyphens---e.g. `Jose Aruego Castilles Cervantes`).  Have you read http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want the query order reversed (first and last name flipped), does this do it for you?

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = 'Martin Joe'

SELECT last_name = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 3)
            END
        )
    ,mi = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            END
        )
    ,first_name = (PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 1))
```

This input

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = 'Martin Joe'
```

Would give (I'm guessing Joe is supposed to be fname in this case?)

```
lname   mi      fname
MARTIN  NULL    JOE
```

And this (now Martin is the first name in this case?)

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = 'Martin'
```

Would give:

```
lname   mi      fname
NULL    NULL    MARTIN
```

On a side note, I took the original SQL code in question and used: http://poorsql.com/ to format it, it's handy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional `WHEN` in your first_name `CASE` to account for the collapsed string and the original string being the same length, so that situation will be treated as a first name. Then there has to be a `CASE` on the last_name to insure that the collapsed string and the original string are *not* the same length.

This seems to work:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20) = 'martin'


SELECT first_name = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            WHEN LEN(@name) 
                THEN PARSENAME('..' + UPPER(@name), 1)
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 3)
            END
        )
    ,mi = (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(UPPER(@name)) - 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 2)
            END
        )
    ,last_name = 
        CASE 
          WHEN LEN(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '')) < LEN(UPPER(@name))
              THEN (PARSENAME(REPLACE(UPPER(@name), ' ', '.'), 1))
          ELSE NULL
        END
```